# Using Django REST Framework to display Rich Text Uploading Field

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application running on Python3 which has a basic blogging application set up. In my `Post` model, I have the following set up for the content of a specific post.

```py
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField 

class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
```

I also have the REST framework for Django set up so that when I do a `GET` request to `/api/posts/slug=abc-123` it runs this:

```py
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows posts to be viewed.
    """
    serializer_class = PostSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = Post.objects.all()
       # A bunch of Django filters
       return queryset
```

And would return something like this:

```
{
    "title" : "Abc 123",
    "slug" : "abc-123,
    "content" : "According to a survey, &#39;93% of executives believe
                 that an employee&rsquo;s style of dress at work 
                 influences his/her chance at a promotion&#39;.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>
                 This is more content blah blah blah."
}
```

*(Ignore the fact that the JSON has line breaks, that is for readability, assume it is a correctly formatted JSON file)*

As you can see the `content` of the result has characters like `\r` and `\n`. This gets rendered in Django using this `{{content | safe}}` which works fine when Django is rendering the page, but I want to display this data in a web app that does not use Django as a backend.

Long story short, I need a javascript (or typescript) library that will render the value of `content` the same way that Django does using its built in `safe` filter. **Note** It must be a library independant of Django that can be used solely on the client side.

**Or**, I need a way to store the content that still allows for all the features of `RichTextUploadingField` in Django, and does not affect Django's rendering, but allows me to render the content in `HTML` in some way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested code,you can have a try:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_content(self, instance):
        from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
        return mark_safe(instance.content)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: SerializerMethodField is read only field. So I cant uge to upload data. any solution?